# How to prove the following inequality with absolute values?

Tags: inequality

Prove that $$x|x - 3| \le 2x^2 - 9x + 12,\: \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$$

I don't know where to begin with this proof. Shall I consider different cases? Assuming that the absolute value is true, then we have:

$$LHS = x^2-3x <= x^2- 3x + 12$$

then keep going from here until we get RHS.

But I don't know if this is a correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since $2x^2-9x+12>0$ and $|a|\geq a$, it's enough to prove that
$$x(x-3)\leq2x^2-9x+12$$ or
$$x^2-6x+12\geq0$$ or
$$(x-3)^2+3\geq0.$$
Done!

Answer (score 1):

> Assuming that the absolute value is true, then we have:

By "true" you probably mean $|x-3|=x-3$, which holds for $x-3 \ge 0 \iff x \ge 3$. If you want to show it holds for all $x$, this is half of the work. For $x \le 3$, you have $|x-3|=-(x-3)$.

Answer (score 1):

for $$x\geq 3$$ we get$$x(x-3)\le 2x^2-9x+12$$ or
$$0\le x^2-6x+12$$ which is true.
if $$x<0$$ we get
$$-x(x-3)\le 2x^2-9x+12$$ or
$$0\le 3x^2-12x+12$$ dividing by $3$ and factorizing we have
$$0\le (x-3)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $$x|x−3|\leq 2x^2−9x+12$$

We can consider this as two cases:

\begin{align}x(x-3)&\leq 2x^2-9x+12\tag{1}\\
&\text{or}\\
x(-(x-3))&\leq2x^2-9x+12\tag{2}\end{align}

Now we can solve each of these:

$(1)$:

\begin{align}x(x-3)&\leq2x^2-9x+12\\
x^2-3x&\leq2x^2-9x+12\\
0&\leq x^2-6x+12\\
&\Downarrow\\
x&\in\Bbb R\end{align}

That is to say, all values of $x$ satisfy this equation.

$(2)$:

\begin{align}x(-(x-3))&\leq2x^2-9x+12\\
x(3-x)&\leq2x^2-9x+12\\
3x-x^2&\leq2x^2-9x+12\\
0&\leq 3x^2-12x+12\\
0&\leq x^2-4x+4\\
0&\leq (x-2)^2\\
&\Downarrow\\
x&\in\Bbb R\end{align}

Again, all values of $x$ satisfy this equation.

Therefore we can conclude that $x\in \Bbb R$ solves the original equation.

We can [plot the two graphs in question](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%7Cx-3%7C,+2x%5E2-9x%2B12) and see that this is true.

Answer (score 1):

We have to prove that:

$$x|x - 3| \le 2x^2 - 9x + 12$$

A correct and complete proof is to consider two different cases:

- $x \ge 3$:
  $$x|x - 3| = x\cdot(x-3) = x^2-3x$$$$x^2-3x\le2x^2-9x+12$$
  Subtracting $x^2-3$ from both sides, we get:$$0\le x^2-6x + 12, \text{ which is true } \forall\:x\ge3$$
- $x \le 3$:
  $$x|x - 3| = x\cdot(3-x) = 3x-x^2$$$$3x-x^2\le2x^2-9x+12$$
  Subtracting $3x-x^2$ from both sides, we get:
  $$0\le 2x^2-9x+12-(3x-x^2)$$
  $$0\le 3x^2-12x+12$$
  $$0\le 3(x^2-4x+4)$$
  $$\frac{0}{3}\le (x-2)^2$$
  $$0\le (x-2)^2, \text{which is true because a square is always non-negative}$$

You have proved that $\forall\:x\in\mathbb{R},\: x\cdot |x-3|\le 2x^2-9x+12$